# Multiple spring jpa entities persistence from cloud api to on prem database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am facing a very peculiar problem related to an api. This api has multiple jpa entity saves into multiple database tables. The api is deployed in cloud and the database is in on prem. We are using spring data crudrepository and jparepository for persistence. We are aware of the network lag in between cloud and on prem infrastructure and currently my firm is not ready to move the database to cloud or use any aws component between api and database. Also stored proc option is out of the table. So keeping all the restrictions we have to optimize the saving of entities in the tables. The intention is to see if this persistence can happen with lesser network call instead of multiple saves. Below is the example

We tried repo.save/saveall and repo.saveAndflush but same performance. It would be great help if there can be a batch solution to a problem where with fewer call we can persist multiple entity in multiple database.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How many entities are you inserting ? By default, jparepository will insert entity one by one. You can tell jpa to use batching while insert. Or you can go full native.

Comment: Around 25 entities.. How does batch insert come here when there is multiple entity inserts in multiple tables?

Comment: I don't see any solution other than going native. Your db may support multi insert in multiple tables or you can use stored procedures.